# How to create surround sound from 2 different audio outputs on PC?

Tags: windows, surround-sound, audio-output

So i have external Digital Audio Converter with 2 channels where i get signal to my active front speakers and sub. But i wish i could get signal simultaneously to my rear speakers from motherboard to create 4.1 surround sound.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your hardware some motherboards have multichannel outputs. In case your motherboard supports this, there should either be a digital output that supports multichannel sound. Or several normal outputs that you can directly connect to the active speakers.

If your hardware does not support this I'm afraid I cannot help you.